# Subseting data and summerise it based on many conditions and groups in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I need to subset a data frame and compute some summaries based on different groups combination of the two categorical variables: Membership and Sex.
For instance:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame( YEAR = c("1999", "1999", "1999", "1999", "2001", "2000","2000", "2000", 
"1999","2000", "2000","1999", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2001"),
Sex=c("M", "M","M", "F", "M","M", "F","F", "F", "M", "F","F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F"),
Membership = rep(c("YES", "NO"), each = 2), 
Income  = sample(1:10000, 17), 
Taxes = sample(1:100, 17))
```

For each year and each of the four possible group combinations (M, Yes), (M, NO), (F, Yes), (F, NO) I need to find out what is the ratio between the total income of each group and the grand income of all groups for that year. The same  applies for taxes column.

For instance, for 1999 and (M, N) the output should be (986+4233)/986+4233+9954+4776+8536) =0.1832

Any idea on how to get it?
Thank you

Comment: Please use `set.seed`.  Also, the example is giving some errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this...

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(YEAR, Sex, Membership) %>%
  summarize(GroupIncome = sum(Income), GroupTaxes = sum(Taxes)) %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>%
  mutate(TotalIncomeForYear = sum(GroupIncome),
         GroupPercentIncome = GroupIncome / TotalIncomeForYear,
         TotalTaxesForYear = sum(GroupTaxes),
         GroupPercentTaxes = GroupTaxes / TotalTaxesForYear) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Which yields a dataframe like this...

[image: Calculation results]

Comment: This is exactly what I need and it solved out my question entirely. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses package `dplyr` to

1. Compute `YEAR` totals of `Income` and `Taxes`,
2. compute sums of `Income` and `Taxes` by groups of `YEAR`, `Sex`, `Membership`,
3. in the same instruction, divide these latter totals by the totals by `YEAR` computed earlier.

Ungroup the result.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>%
  mutate(SumYearIncome = sum(Income),
         SumYearTaxes = sum(Taxes)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(YEAR, Sex, Membership) %>%
  mutate(RatioGroupIncome = sum(Income)/SumYearIncome,
         RatioGroupTaxes = sum(Taxes)/SumYearTaxes) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-SumYearIncome, -SumYearTaxes)
```